# PHP Unserialize Removing Object Property

Tags: php, exception, serialization, pdo, php-7.1

I have code that is serializing a `PDOException`, sending it over the wire, and then unserializing it later on. When I unserialize it, the `$code` property appears to be missing. The rest of the object appears unchanged.

My code is running against a PostgreSQL database. Use the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INTEGER
);
```

Use the following code to reproduce my issue (substituting your own PostgeSQL connection values):

```
<?php

$dsn = "pgsql: dbname=postgres;host=/var/run/postgresql;port=5432";
$user = "postgres";
$password = "";
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $res = $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (999999999999999)");
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    var_dump((array) $e);
    print "\n";
    print $e->getCode();
    print "\n";
    $s = serialize($e);
    print $s;
    print "\n";
    $d = unserialize($s);
    var_dump((array) $d);
    print "\n";
    print $d->getCode();
    print "\n";
    print serialize($e->getCode());
    print "\n";
}

?>
```

In my output, the `$code` property is missing from the final output. Additionally I get the following notice:

`PHP Notice:  Undefined property: PDOException::$code in /home/developer/test_serialize.php on line 20`

I'm finding that I actually have to execute a failing SQL statement in order to see this issue. In particular if I pick, for example, the wrong port number, then I'll get a `PDOException` but it will retain the `$code` property after `unserialize` call.

Note that the serialized string appears to have the code property there, so I'm assuming this is an issue with the `unserialize` function.

Any insight would be appreciated - am I misunderstanding something fundamental here? Is this a PHP bug? Something else? I'm on the following PHP version:

```
PHP 7.1.6 (cli) (built: Jun 18 2018 12:25:10) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

**Edit - Adding Print Output**

The following is the output of the reproduction script. Note that I've modified is slightly to add some newlines for readability, and replacing `print_r` with `var_dump`:

```
array(8) {
  ["*message"]=>
  string(75) "SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 7 ERROR:  integer out of range"
  ["Exceptionstring"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["*code"]=>
  string(5) "22003"
  ["*file"]=>
  string(34) "/home/developer/test_serialize.php"
  ["*line"]=>
  int(10)
  ["Exceptiontrace"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(34) "/home/developer/test_serialize.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(10)
      ["function"]=>
      string(4) "exec"
      ["class"]=>
      string(3) "PDO"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(73) "INSERT INTO km_role (role_id, role_name) VALUES (999999999999999, 'test')"
      }
    }
  }
  ["Exceptionprevious"]=>
  NULL
  ["errorInfo"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "22003"
    [1]=>
    int(7)
    [2]=>
    string(28) "ERROR:  integer out of range"
  }
}

22003
O:12:"PDOException":8:{s:10:"*message";s:75:"SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 7 ERROR:  integer out of range";s:17:"Exceptionstring";s:0:"";s:7:"*code";s:5:"22003";s:7:"*file";s:34:"/home/developer/test_serialize.php";s:7:"*line";i:10;s:16:"Exceptiontrace";a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:"file";s:34:"/home/developer/test_serialize.php";s:4:"line";i:10;s:8:"function";s:4:"exec";s:5:"class";s:3:"PDO";s:4:"type";s:2:"->";s:4:"args";a:1:{i:0;s:73:"INSERT INTO km_role (role_id, role_name) VALUES (999999999999999, 'test')";}}}s:19:"Exceptionprevious";N;s:9:"errorInfo";a:3:{i:0;s:5:"22003";i:1;i:7;i:2;s:28:"ERROR:  integer out of range";}}
array(7) {
  ["*message"]=>
  string(75) "SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 7 ERROR:  integer out of range"
  ["Exceptionstring"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["*file"]=>
  string(34) "/home/developer/test_serialize.php"
  ["*line"]=>
  int(10)
  ["Exceptiontrace"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(34) "/home/developer/test_serialize.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(10)
      ["function"]=>
      string(4) "exec"
      ["class"]=>
      string(3) "PDO"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(73) "INSERT INTO km_role (role_id, role_name) VALUES (999999999999999, 'test')"
      }
    }
  }
  ["Exceptionprevious"]=>
  NULL
  ["errorInfo"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "22003"
    [1]=>
    int(7)
    [2]=>
    string(28) "ERROR:  integer out of range"
  }
}

PHP Notice:  Undefined property: PDOException::$code in /home/developer/test_serialize.php on line 24

s:5:"22003"
```

In the example where the PDOException is thrown via incorrect port number, the serialized `$e->getCode()` is:

```
i:7;
```

Comment: If you are using namespaces then try adding slash before `PDOException` as `\PDOException`.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh I've tried with and without - no difference

Comment: Thanks for adding the bounty, @jh1711 :)

Comment: What are the excact outputs of the print_r statements (can you make it var_dump and edit the question)?

Comment: @RobGwynn-Jones, welcome; I'm interested in this issue myself. Could you add the outputs of `serialize($e->getCode());` for your reproducer and the wrong-port-number example.

Comment: Just been playing with this and tried the similar code in mysqli_ and it actually works!  So looks like something in PDO

Comment: Sorry for my absence. @jstur 's answer nailed the solution using Reflection. If you want to file a bug report with PHP: [This](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=4d2278143a08b7522de9471d0f014d7357c28fea) is the commit that limits `$code` to int only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blackbam's answer is exceptional, but the PDO object being unserializable is a red herring. The problem with your code really is due to the type of the `$code` property, as discussed in the comments to his post. The exception is initialized with a string representation of the error code instead of an integer in some circumstances. This breaks deserialization, which very reasonably decides to discard properties with invalid types.

The comments on the [PDOException documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) are almost all talking about problems caused by the error code being created as a string instead of an int.

You can set the protected value to an integer using reflection. See below:

```
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $res = $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO test_schema.test (id) VALUES (999999999999999)");
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    // the new bit is here
    if (!is_int($e->getCode())) {
        $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($e);
        $reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('code');
        $reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
        $reflectionProperty->setValue($e, (int)$reflectionProperty->getValue($e));    
    }
    // the rest is the same
    var_dump((array) $e);
    print "\n";
    print $e->getCode();
    print "\n";
    $s = serialize($e);
    print $s;
    print "\n";
    $d = unserialize($s);
    var_dump((array) $d);
    print "\n";
    print $d->getCode();
    print "\n";
    print serialize($e->getCode());
    print "\n";
}
```

Of course, you will lose information if the code contains an alphanumeric value rather than an integer cast as a string. The message may duplicate the error number, but that may not be great to rely on.

The unserializable stack trace Blackbam is concerned with can become a problem if you tweak your code just a little bit:

```
function will_crash($pdo) {
    $res = $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO test_schema.test (id) VALUES (999999999999999)");
}

try
{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    will_crash($pdo);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $s = serialize($e);
    // PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances in...
}
```

Whoops.

So Blackbam's answer, and the approach in his link of creating a serializable exception class, is probably the way to go. That allows you to serialize an exception's data but not the stack trace.

Then again, at that point you may as well just use `json_encode` and `json_decode` to pass around/store exception information.

Comment: Fascinating - thanks for the great answer. I wasn't aware `ReflectionClass` could be used in that way and that was definitely the missing link for me. Do you know why a fatal error is thrown when the PDO call is made in a function like that, but not when the call was inline? I'm going to accept this answer because it provides a proof of / solution to the stated issue of the missing `$code` property. In regards to the obvious XY problem of trying to serialize a `PDOException`, I agree the correct answer is not to try. Thanks for taking the time to look at this problem.

Comment: Ah, I just re-read @Blackbam's answer and I think I understand why your modification throws the error - because passing the `$pdo` object to a function means the stack trace is one level deeper and now includes a PDO object, which can't be serialized. Ouch.

Comment: @RobGwynn-Jones Yes, that's it. I wish I could pretend I knew all of this before -- Blackbam's answer is really exceptional and I learned a bit piecing the rest of it together.

Comment: Great answer; I didn't know the trick with reflections. [Here](https://3v4l.org/GuaoI) is a small reproducer that shows that exceptions don't like strings and when it was introduced (you may have to click on 'eol versions'.

Answer (score 5):

First of all have a look at the PDOException class:

```
PDOException extends RuntimeException {
  /* Properties */
  public array $errorInfo ;
  protected string $code ;

  /* Inherited properties */
  protected string $message ;
  protected int $code ;
  protected string $file ;
  protected int $line ;

  /* Inherited methods */
  final public string Exception::getMessage ( void )
  final public Throwable Exception::getPrevious ( void )
  final public mixed Exception::getCode ( void )
  final public string Exception::getFile ( void )
  final public int Exception::getLine ( void )
  final public array Exception::getTrace ( void )
  final public string Exception::getTraceAsString ( void )
  public string Exception::__toString ( void )
  final private void Exception::__clone ( void )
}
```

The getCode() method in PHP is implemented just like this (ref: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/cd953269d3d486f775f1935731b1d6d44f12a350/ext/spl/spl.php):

```
/** @return the code passed to the constructor
 */
final public function getCode()
{
    return $this->code;
}
```

This is the constructor of a PHP Exception:

```
/** Construct an exception
 *
 * @param $message Some text describing the exception
 * @param $code    Some code describing the exception
 */
function __construct($message = NULL, $code = 0) {
    if (func_num_args()) {
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    $this->code = $code;
    $this->file = __FILE__; // of throw clause
    $this->line = __LINE__; // of throw clause
    $this->trace = debug_backtrace();
    $this->string = StringFormat($this);
}
```

What does that tell us? *The `$code` property of an Exception can only be populated when the Exception is generated and it should be zero if no `$code` was passed.*

So is this a PHP Bug? I guess not, after some research I have found the following great article: http://fabien.potencier.org/php-serialization-stack-traces-and-exceptions.html

In essence it says:

When PHP serializes an exception, it serializes the exception code, the exception message, but also the stack trace.

The stack trace is an array containing all functions and methods that have already been executed at this point of the script. The trace contains the file name, the line in the file, the function name, and an array of all arguments passed to the function. Do you spot the problem?

The stack trace contains a reference to the PDO instance, as it was passed to the will_crash() function, and as PDO instances are not serializable, an exception is thrown when PHP serializes the stack trace.

> **Whenever a non-serializable object is present in the stack trace, the
>   exception won't be serializable.**

*And I guess this is the reason why our serialize()/unserialize() process is failing - because the Exception is not serializable.*

**Solution:**

> Write a Serializable Exception which extends Exception

```
class SerializableException extends Exception implements Serializable {
// ... go ahead :-)
}
```

Comment: Nice writeup about the problems you can run into when (un)serializing exceptions. But I don't think non-serializable objects are the reason for the issue in this question. `serialize` and `unserialize` don't crash; there's just a missing property. I also don't understand how one can force PDO to throw a different exception. So I'm not sure how extending the class can help. But maybe I missed something.

Comment: $code is defined before serializing the Exception but not afterwards therefore there must be a problem with the serialization right?  Any chance that it just fails silently and PHP simply goes on though the serialization does not work as expected?

Comment: Right now I have the theory that PDO sometimes throws an exception with the wrong type for $code; but it throws other exceptions with the correct type. I have no idea why, but I I think I can explain why it affects (un)serialization. I'll wait for another 24-48 hours to give OP a change to reply to my comment, since he can confirm or refute my theory. After that I think I can (hopefully) safely award the bounty to you for the tremendous value your answer added towards solving this and similar problems.

Comment: Cliffs: Yes, PHP silently discards properties of the wrong type.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Sure lets wait for the OP and see what he thinks about all this. The bounty is just one day old lets see if somebody else can add some value though I think that we probably got it 

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated the original post with print outputs as requested, along with the serialized error code. Note that when I give PDO an invalid port the code property is an integer, and when the trace actually contains a PDO object, i.e. when it's tried to run a SQL statement, it's a string. So what's the prevailing theory? That it's the fact that it's trying to serialize a PDO instance? The datatype change of `$code` is documented so it seems unlikely to me that it'd be a type mismatch, but I could be wrong. What would be a good way to test this theory?

Comment: Well it MIGHT be a type missmatch (good point), but I think the core problem occurs because you cannot rely on serializing Exceptions. Though it is strange that only the $code property is missing and everything else seems to work. However this problem might justify a bug report in order to get clarity: http://php.net/manual/en/install.problems.bugs.php . You might want to create an issue and link it here?

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed answer. @jstur's answer more directly hits the nail on the head though so I'll be accepting his answer. I do appreciate the time you took to investigate this problem and I've upvoted this answer as well.

Comment: Sure thank you too. I also upvoted @jstur's answer for adding the missing information regarding the code property and the great idea with the reflection class.

Comment: Sorry for my absence. I just awarded the bounty to @jstor, because I think that it is more on point for this question. I hope you don't feel this is a bait and switch;I did not plan to to it this way. If I find a way to make it up, I will.

Comment: The system says we have to wait 24 hours. I hope I won't disappear again ;)

Comment: @jh1711 No problem both answers added important value while jstur indeed is a bit more on point at the end to this specific question. I also upvoted him 